# Convert multiple files using Mercurial's Filter System

Tags: mercurial, filter, zip, encode

Is it possible to convert multiple, on-each-other-depending files using a filter?

E.g. instead of converting `a.zip to a.txt` and `b.zip to b.txt` is it possible to convert `a.zip AND b.zip to ab.txt`? 
The problem is that a.zip and b.zip can't be converted individually, since a.zip contains data which is needed for the conversion of b.zip.

Using the tempfile option creates only one (temp-)file, and passes only this file's name to the converter's-executable.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking.  The convert extension/command doesn't have a `filter` option -- it has `filemap`, `splicemap`, and `branchmap` which all do some sort of filtering.  The transplant command/extension has `filter` but you didn't mention transplant.  Waht tempfile option are you referring to?  Perhaps provide an example of converting a.zip into a.txt so we can see just what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

No, I'm afraid the [decode/encode filter system](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#decode-encode) works on single files only.

Internally, the filter system is used by [three methods in the `localrepo` class](http://selenic.com/hg/file/1.6.4/mercurial/localrepo.py#l547). These functions operate on working copy file names.